# add event into the loader in flex 4 air

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

I would like to know if it's possible to add some jobs on the onload of my air app, what I mean is:
I have an eventHandler which get the event "FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE" but this event it`s dispatched after the progress bar ends, I would like to know if there is some event that I can handler and add my jobs there?!?

Or the only way to do this, it's doing a custom preloader??, like the link bellow:

[Custom Preloader in Flex 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146314/custom-preloader-in-flex-4)

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2):

There are four events that an Application dispatches during its creation and initial display:

1. `preinitialize`
2. `initialize`
3. `creationComplete`
4. `applicationComplete`

More info at Adobe: [About Startup Order](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee6.html)

**EDIT:**

However, the Application itself is not instantiated until *after* all the RSL's have loaded, ie., when the Preloader fires an Event.COMPLETE (for that part of the preload).  The `preinitialize` event on the Application should get fired while the Preloader is still displayed, but the initialization phase might just be much faster relative to the other loading phases.  So, yes, if you want to do something concurrent to the Preloader loading RSL's, you have to write a custom preloader.

Comment: Not working actually, it`s still running my job, after the loader bar finish

Comment: @Arthur - Totally sorry about that--my initial answer was just plain wrong and unhelpful. You are right that you must use a custom Preloader. The Application isn't even instantiated (let alone firing events) until after the Preloader finishes loading RSL's.