# create custom loading page in flex web application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flash-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Preloader in Flex 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146314/custom-preloader-in-flex-4)

I am working with a flex web application and i want to implement custom loading page on application startup like the above http://www.picnik.com/app and i am using Flex3.5 sdk.

How can i achieve that. Any code and link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples out there, but the best ive come accross are the following - had these saved in my gmail account for ages:)

This is the best one ive seen

http://blogagic.com/14/the-blogagic-custom-flex-preloader

Adding an image to the background of the preloader

http://polygeek.com/flex/2742_preloaderBackgroundImage/srcview/index.html