# How to remove preloader of Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I am getting this loader beofre my flash application shows up , how to remove this ? I already have a preloader for my application , but still couldnt find why this one shows up , I want to remove this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Preloader in Flex 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146314/custom-preloader-in-flex-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to extend `SparkDownloadProgressBar` from `mx.preloaders.SparkDownloadProgressBar`

then use the preloader property of the main application tag; for example:

```
<s:Application preloader=”com.riagora.loader.Preloader”>
```

take a look at [Building a custom Flex preloader](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-custom-preloader.html)